# Personal Reports We Are Entitled to BY LAW (Other than Credit Reports from Experian, Equifax, Transunion)

Tags: consumer-protection, us-federal-government

Are there personal reports US citizens are  BY LAW, entitled to other than credit reports from Experian, Equifax and Transunion.

For instance, I could have sworn I saw a government website on MIB, i.e. your personal medical information that insurance companies have on you. Now I cannot seem to find it on any government website that says we are entitled to this report BY LAW.

Two part question

1a - Where is US government website where person can requesting free copy of their MIB (online or by phone). And I don't mean MIB.com. I am looking for government website that would reference something like MIB, i.e. for instance [Federal Trade Commission website](https://www.ftc.gov/faq/consumer-protection/get-my-free-credit-report) references [annualcreditreport.com](https://www.annualcreditreport.com/index.action)

1b - Where is US government website where person can requesting free copy of their other personal records (online or by phone)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about the law.

Comment: The question "Which personal reports are we legally entitled to receive?" would be on-topic, though maybe too broad.  I agree that asking where to find the website is not about law and is off-topic.

Comment: This is very much a question about the law. Check out the Privacy Act of 1974.

Comment: @bdb484 a question about the Privacy Act would be on topic - this isn’t one. It’s a question about where to find information that may tangentially be related to the law.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the first sentence asks about what a person is "entitled to," which is a question about what the law requires. Even the questions about where to find the information to which one is entitled are questions about how to exercise one's rights under that law.

Comment: So it's at best unclear or too broad, and should be closed until it is made clear and precise. Why do users have such an aversion to using the system we've got and maintaining the standard expected?

Comment: I updated the question by adding `BY LAW`. By Law, US citizens are entitled to free annual credit report from each of the three credit bureaus. I wanted to know if there are other reports we are entitled to  `BY LAW`

Comment: Questions about website locations aren't legal, and falsely assumes that the government has a duty provide "records". You should remove all of that stuff from the question and simply ask about laws compelling disclosure. Plus, what is this MIB that you are referring to? Which kinds of records are you asking about?

Comment: You are entitled to an annual statement of Social Security tax received, by year. It includes an estimate of your retirement benefit, which can be changed by law.

Comment: I have no doubt that this is on topic (at least as edited). It is about a legal right to obtain certain information. It is hard to comprehensively list these as there isn't any one list, but an answer could certainly list many such reports and kinds of information. FOIA is a big one too. Limiting it to federal U.S. law probably makes it not too broad even though it is hard to answer comprehensively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1a - Where is US government website where person can requesting free
>   copy of their MIB (online or by phone). And I don't mean MIB.com. I am
>   looking for government website that would reference something like
>   MIB, i.e. for instance Federal Trade Commission website references
>   annualcreditreport.com

There isn't one.

The right to medical information is a right you have vis-a-vis individual heath care providers and insurance companies that have your medical information. The U.S. government does not have access to this information and doesn't facilitate you getting this information, except that you could sue in federal court to get it if the person required by law to provide it to you didn't give it to you.

(The fact that the U.S. government does not have access to individual health information is one of the reasons that major medical research studies that capture a sample of the entire population of a country for a given time period are often done instead in foreign countries that have comprehensive medical records databases. In the U.S., the best possible alternative is often to look at the medical records of servicemen and veterans who received government provided health care, or to create very large voluntarily long term studies of populations such as doctors and nurses.)

Even in the case of credit reports, the government website merely ends up directing you to a private sector website maintained by credit reporting websites and is not a government website.

> 1b - Where is US government website where person can requesting free
>   copy of their other personal records (online or by phone)

You can apply to the U.S. government via one of the IRS websites to get transcript of your past tax returns for a certain number of years.

You can apply to the Social Security Administration to get your earnings history for Social Security purposes and I think that can be done from their website or by telephone.

There is a U.S. government website called PACER at which you can get copies of all non-sealed filings in all federal court cases, and all filings in court cases to which you are or have been a party.

There is U.S. government website at which you can ascertain whether or not a building, including your home, is in a flood plain.

There is a U.S. government website that allows you to locate people who are currently incarcerated in federal prison.

There is a U.S. government website that allows you to review census data from time periods when almost everybody is dead. I believe that old immigration records can also be accessed in this manner.

There is a phone number at the Veteran's Administration where veterans can ask about their personal veteran's benefits. I'm not sure if that have a website from which they can do so yet. Last time I checked, a long time ago, they didn't.

There are several websites and phone numbers that federal employees can access to get their personnel record type information.

This is absolutely not a comprehensive list.

It shouldn't be hard for you to research yourself the current web address for these sites which changes fairly often anyway.

You can get many other kinds of information from the U.S. government that is about you via the Freedom of Information Act (a.k.a. FOIA), but generally speaking, this information isn't available via a website or by phone. Usually, you have to request it in a written letter or application unless a new website allowing you to do this that I don't know about has been created recently.

Comment: Well this is a great start!